# Extra information when asking a question: What is the actual problem?

Tags: feature-request

Just recently I posted the content below as an answer, but I feel like there might be an easy solution to the problem: *People don't ask for help with their problem, but they ask for help with what they think is the solution.*

I see it all the time on SO (and any other helpdesk/forum) and unfortunately it mainly involves the non-lazy people. They tried to find a solution to their problem as requested/advised by SO, but they are only searching for solutions within the scope of their knowledge. After a few hours of messing around in copy/pasted code they ask for help with their solution, without mentioning the original problem that their solution is intended to solve.

Example PHP Problem (simplified):

> How can I parse the following string to a key/value array?
>
> ```
> "key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4"
> ```

Solution tried:

> - Explode (split) on &
> - Loop the resulting array and explode each value on =
> - save the results to an array
>
>   ```
>   <?php
>   $str = "key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4";
>   $ar1 = explode(";", $str);
>   for ($i=0;$i<count($ar1);$i++) {
>     $ar2 = explode("=", $ar1[$i]);
>     $result[$ar2[0]] = $ar2[1]; //error for key 4 since there is no =
>   }
>   ?>
>   ```

Question asked:

> Why do I get a warning that an index is undefined?

Answer:

> You should use `array_key_exists`

Now the question is answered, since there won't be a warning any more. But if he actually asked for a solution to his problem the answer would be:

> use `parse_str($str, $result);`

Now since this often involves the non-lazy people, people that often do read information on how to ask a question, it might be enough to just add an information block in the "Ask a question" page, similar to "How to ask". Perhaps something like:

> Make sure that you mention what your actual problem is and not just why your solution isn't working. There might be a better way to reach your goal.

In my opinion this will benefit the site and the people. The questions become more clear, the answers will focus on the actual problem and the asker will learn something new.

Comment: You're describing [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887)

Comment: I guess I am. I never heared that term before so I couldnt find any previous questions about it. But I doubt anybody that wants to ask a question will first search meta for `XY problem` and then use the info correctly. So my request still stands, but the info block could use a reference to the link you provided.

Comment: I am a bit confused about what feature you're requesting here...

Comment: A specific mention of the XY problem in the "Ask a question screen". Since thats is the problem i encounter the most when answering questions. And it might be in the FAQ on meta, but its not in the helpcenter at stackoverflow.

Comment: People often aren't even aware of their problems. Even mentioning the XY problem explicitly would probably not prevent anyone from posting XY questions. I don't think you'll ever going to get rid of the typical problem questions ever, no matter how tired we are of them. There's always going to be a spectrum of questions, you will never be able to just filter in on the good end of the spectrum. XY questions are a part of life.